# save data in json local storage with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, local-storage

I have this form

```
<form ng-submit="addState()">
            <input ng-model="text1" type="text">
            <input ng-model="text2" type="text">
            <input ng-model="text3" type="text">     
</form>
```

and this JS

```
mainAppControllers.controller('DoarScanCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location){

    }
]);
```

So First i need save the data in local storage and after this i need have a json

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the data you want to save to localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this lib https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage it also auto convert object and array to json

```
localStorageService.set("model", $scope.model);

$scope.model2= localStorageService.get("model");
```

i made a fiddle how to use http://jsfiddle.net/jgs4280c/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several of the available local storage packages and settled for https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage

It is quite simplistic, but it works very reliably compared to others.

And you can both bind your ng-model directly to the local storage key and then it's done, or you can use legacy style getter/setter where that suits better.