# Angular.js - $http.get - use cache from file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, caching, angularjs-http

Is it possible to use a file (.js / .json) the angular.js cache for $http.get?

We have an angular application, and we want to download some pages and view them offline.
So, the idea is, before downloading, we make all the necessary $http.get calls, and save the responses in some json / js file. When we open the pages offline, we want the $http.get calls to access this file and use it as a cache.

It sounds like it should be possible, but I'm new to angular, so I'm not sure how to configure that.

Comment: Maybe you can use web storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), but it requires some additional logic in your code

Comment: Update, I found interesting module: http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/ which probably resolve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217824/javascript-http-get-an-json-array-and-store-it-in-localstorage

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117729/save-data-in-json-local-storage-with-angularjs

Should help

Comment: thanks, I'll look into this...

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise following techniques:

1. Browser's localStorage, [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)
2. Service worker to intelligently recache requests, [configurable plugin sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) for you build tool

Besides that:

- you can enable caching of `$http.get` requests:

  $http({ cache: true, url: url, method: 'GET'}).success(...);
- you can make use of angular `$templateCache` : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Answer (score 0):

Hey this might help you    [jsCache](https://github.com/funwithjs/jsCache)

You can store api data in storage of your choice for desired time period you want.
Just have an look @ https://github.com/funwithjs/jsCache

Comment: you should have added a note that you're the author of this lib